# Map column values to a a numeric type in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a df in spark which as the following structure:

```
amount gender status
1000   male   married
1313   female single
1000   male   married
```

Basically i want to create new column where gender is a number

```
amount gender status  gender_num
1000   male   married 1
1313   female single  2
1000   male   married 1
```

I tired the following:

```
  val gender = df.gender

  val gender_num = gender match {
case male => 1
case female => 2
}
```

I get the following error:

```
<console>:125: error: value pa_gender_category is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
val gender = data.pa_gender_category
```

I know there is a stringtoindex function, but i would like to do this manually

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `withColumn`

```
val input = // load input DataFrame
val withGender = input.withColumn("gender_num", when($"gender" === "female", 2).otherwise(1))
```

You can chain more options:

```
val withGender = input.withColumn("gender_num", when($"gender" === "female", 2).when($"gender" == "other", 3).otherwise(1))
```

You can also use UDF like in Akash's answer. Be aware, that sometimes UDFs cannot be optimized as much as built-in functions, but they can be more readable

Comment: Awesome, now how can i extend this to handle say one more class? I promise to up vote if for this!

Comment: @user3875610 I prefer this answer initially, but in my opinion if you're adding more cases the other answer would be better, this approach will become unwieldy and harder to read.

Comment: @ImDarrenG Depends on the use case. Case-When can be optimized, UDF probably not, but sometimes they're more readable

Comment: @ImDarrenG I agree, but for me this looks a lot like ifelse code, so this has that appeal to me. Fully agree with your comments!

Comment: @T.Gawęda true, now you have edited to add the third case it does looks fine :) do you think it would make more sense to explicitly check for "male" and default to "other"? nitpicking! :)

Comment: @ImDarrenG Random order, I'm in work and I'm writing in breaks.. So I didn't want to edit more than it's necessary to show use case :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use UDF of Spark

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
def genderToNumber: UserDefinedFunction = {
    udf((gender: String) => {
                             gender match {
                                           case "male" => 1
                                           case "female" => 2
                                          }
                          }               })
```

You can apply UDF by this

```
   val newDF = df.withColumn("gender_num", genderToNumber(df("gender")))
```

Comment: Thanks Akash, liked the use of switch statements

Comment: 1. You need `case "male"` and `case "female"`. This function will always evaluate to `1`. 2. Everything within `udf` can be simplified to just `{ case "male" => ... }`